# Question about word choice in this sentence: "Although he’ll be moving into a postdoctoral position soon, he's going to miss John."

Tags: word-choice

Do people usually say someone is "moving" into a postdoctoral position? Or is there another word?

Comment: I've heard moving used this way. Also taking up a new position.

Comment: It isn't clear whether _he_ or _John_ is moving, and it isn't clear why _although_ would be used. And people could say _moving into a postdoctoral position_, but probably wouldn't, since quite often you just move up to a postdoc where you are. Moving where you live is a separate issue. If you want to mention the postdoc, do it in a different clause from the moving.

Comment: If you want to emphasize that he's leaving his current institution and going somewhere else, then it sounds better to say that he's "**moving on to** a postdoctoral position".

Answer (score -1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> It isn't clear whether *he* or *John* is moving, and it isn't clear why *although* would be used. And people could say *moving into a postdoctoral position*, but probably wouldn't, since quite often you just move up to a postdoc where you are. Moving where you live is a separate issue. If you want to mention the postdoc, do it in a different clause from the moving.